# ViewController Xcode Link Issue

Tags: xcode

Just started using xcode recently, needed help.

So, I have a NavigationController linking to a WebBroswerViewController. However, when I added a ViewController which served as my home page, It would not launch when linked to the NavigationController. How can I resolve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using storyboards select the View you wanna set as Home then in the xcode top menu go to Editor->Embed In->Navigation Controller 
This should set your selected View as first View when you run the project.
(I think you should also delete the NavigationController you already created)

Comment: I did what you said...it didn't work, just popped up with this line highlighted in green:         return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([IDZAppDelegate class]));

Comment: Copy the error log it gives you maybe I can find out where's the problem

Comment: There's no error log, just directs me to this:  //
//  main.m
//  IDZWebBrowser
//
//  Created by idz on 11/16/13.
//  Copyright (c) 2013 iOSDeveloperZone.com. All rights reserved.
//

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

#import "IDZAppDelegate.h"

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool {
        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([IDZAppDelegate class]));
    }
}

Comment: I think you didn't set your navigation controller correctly,
does your project look like this? (Don't look at the elements inside the Views, just make sure the links between the Views are the same as the example)

http://nscookbook.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/NavigationControllerStoryboard.png

Comment: Similar, It used to be just the NavigationController linked to the UIWebView, which successfully loaded my webview.  Until I added the viewcontroller for my home page...which won't load

Comment: The error it gives you could be everything.. delete the navigation Controller and recreate every link between the views maybe there's an error there

Comment: How do i delete the navigationcontroller I created in the storyboard?

Comment: just select it and press the canc button then recreate it with the method I listed above:
Editor->Embed In->Navigation Controller

Comment: tried everything, nothing's working.. simulator just goes black. Is there any specific code I need for the ViewController?

Comment: np glad I could help! :) Check my answer as correct so if someone has your same problem they'll find the solution

Comment: just did, btw part of the problem was that when I added "IAD Banner View" for my app it refused to load. Strange. Would you happen to know why?

Comment: First thing I can think of is that maybe you forgot to create the Outlet for your AD Banner View.. but dunno, there are lot of possible causes

Comment: Yea I didn't, would you be able to provide me with the outlet code as I just started using Xcode 3 days ago!

Comment: You don't need to write code, outlets are automatically created when you link an object (in your case the banner view) to your .h file.
To do so you have to press the 2nd icon on the top right of Xcode, it's called 'Assistant Editor' and you should see something like this:
http://www.techotopia.com/images/e/ed/Xcode_assistant_editor.png
Then you have to select your banner view, press ctrl and drag the line inside the code, xcode will ask you how to name the element and the work is done. But I recommend you to read some basic tutorial in order to have an idea on how outlets works!

Comment: it doesnt let me add it to my .h file. Ive done this a few times before and its worked fine